# How to throw/return an error message in javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

So this is the code in my index file that's meant to catch the error:

```
router.post('/addproducer', async ctx => {
try {
    const body = ctx.request.body
    const database = await new Producers(dbName)
    await database.addProducer(body.name)
    ctx.redirect('/list')
} catch(err) {
    ctx.body = err.message
}
})
```

and this is the code in my modules file that I want to throw that error, but I am not sure how to do that:

```
    //Add function to add producers to database if not existing or add product types if producer exists. 
async addProducer(name) {

    console.log('Add Producer', name)
    
    //Check if there are any Producers with the same name
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM producers WHERE name="${name}"`
    const data = await this.db.all(sql)
    
    //If producer doesn't exist add to database
    if(data.length === 0) {
        sql = `INSERT INTO producers (name) VALUES("${name}")`
        await this.db.run(sql)
        console.log('Producer successfuly added.')
    }
    
    //Else return error saying producer exists
    else {
        console.log('Producer already exists.')
    }
}
```

It does tell me in the console.log that the producer already exists, but I would like to throw that error so that the index.js file would catch it and show it to the user.

Comment: `throw new Error('Producer already exists.');`

Comment: `throw 'Producer already exists';` <= technically you can `throw` anything.